# Installing .egg file for NLTK

Tags: ubuntu, unix, python

I want to install NLTK on Ubuntu, and I'm following the instructions for UNIX here:

http://nltk.org/install.html

In step 2, I downloaded the egg file. Then I ran

```
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

After I typed it my password, it said

```
sh: 0: Can't open setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

How can I install it?

Comment: Did you set the current directory (i believe the command is `cd [path]`) to the folder the file is contained in? I don't know how many times I've made that mistake.

Comment: @SylvestertheCat Yes, I already checked that I'm at the folder the file is contained in.

Comment: perhaps it's something to do with sudo? try running the command without the preceding `sudo` (i.e. `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`) EDIT: likewise try downloading without using sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu already has `pip` pre-packaged, so installing that is the easiest option (if `setuptools` is not installed it will be installed automatically as a dependency of `pip`):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

followed by (optional):

```
$ sudo pip install -U numpy
```

and:

```
$ sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
```